# how to get the last commiter in jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, perforce

I have a Jenkins pipeline setup that it works with Perforce as SCM I have been trying to find if it is possible to send a slack message(it is already connected to slack to send msgs to a channel on each build) / email to the person who commited in case the build fails, I have found information but all the information I find it is related to Git. Anyone knows where can I find some documentation or examples on how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Try the `GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL` environment variable. Check https://your-jenkins-instance/env-vars.html for a list of available environment variables.

Comment: How are you trying to send the Email? Using a plugin?